# Doctrine seems to ignore my primary keys

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm starting with Symfony2 and Doctrine. After setup symfony and create my new bundle, I stucked at reversing my postgre database. It return an exception at the first table which reads:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\MappingMappingException]                      
  Table tb_core_table has no primary key. Doctrine does not support reverse engineering from tables that don't have a primary key.
```

This is the command I'm executing at command line:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/ak/ProcessamentoBundle/Resources/config/doctrine --from-database --force
```

Ok, by now I already know that all tables have to have pk's so doctrine can work with them, and that is the problem. My "tb_core_table" HAS a primary key, but for any reason, doctrine ignores it.

I'm missing some configuration? Why it can find the primary key?

---

This is my table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_core_table (
    id_table integer NOT NULL,
    id_aux_table integer NOT NULL,
    no_table character varying(255),
    st_table integer
);

CREATE SEQUENCE tb_core_table_id_table_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

ALTER TABLE ONLY tb_core_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT tb_core_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_table);
```

Comment: Post a table def or two from your yaml file. You probably haven't defined it correctly.

Comment: Well, maybe this is the problem. I don't have any definition. From what I could understand, these yaml file would be generated by doctrine from my database.

Comment: In the Doctrine docs, I believe it says that the db schema importer only took you so far. You might need to adjust the definitions as needed.